# Copy records in a table and insert back into the same table with two columns updated

Tags: sql, sql-insert

I want to use records in a table as a template for new records to be added to that same table. I'm trying to create a SQL query that will select the "template" records and then insert those records back into the same table but update two columns.

So my initial SQL would be something like:

```
SELECT * 
FROM CALCDETL 
WHERE CALCFILE = 'TEMPLATE' AND CECODE = 'SUB'
```

and then I want to insert the lines that query returns back into the same table but have the records use an updated `CALCFILE` and `CECODE` value.

Thanks for any help!

Tim

Comment: why not just set default values on the table you plan to insert into?

Comment: you need to show each field, * won't do it

Answer (score 0):

you need to show each field, * won't do it

```
INSER INTO CALCDETL ([col1],[col2],..,CALCFILE, CECODE )
SELECT [col1],[col2]...,NewCALCFILEValue, NewCECODEValue  
  FROM CALCDETL WHERECALCFILE = 'TEMPLATE' AND CECODE = 'SUB'
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
INSERT INTO CALCDETL (col1, col2, ...., colN, CALCFILE, CECODE)
    SELECT 
        col1, col2, col3, ....,   -- all columns *EXCEPT* the two in question 
        NewCalcFileValue, NewCeCodeValue
    FROM 
        CALCDETL 
    WHERE 
        CALCFILE = 'TEMPLATE' AND CECODE = 'SUB'
```

Basically, you select the *template rows* and re-insert them, specifying new values for those two columns in question. In order to do that, you **must** explicitly define the column list in the `INSERT INTO` statement (which is a recommended best practice always), and you also **must specify** the explicit list of columns to select from the template rows (and re-insert unchanged)